# Spring Cloud Config Server - Possibility to reference files with Git backend

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-config-server

As an organisational unit, we have set up Spring Cloud Config Server for all our Spring micro-services with a Git backend (using bitbucket.org). We have also enabled the `/actuator/refresh` endpoints to refresh our `@ConfigurationProperties` on the fly without having to redeploy any micro-service. It was decided not to make use of Spring Cloud Bus to ensure that we have full control when to refresh which application as a precaution.

Now comes our question. We have some micro-services which have queries as configurations. These can be quite cumbersome and we would like to place such queries in a file and have them referenced by the Spring Cloud Config Server. Has anyone managed to come up with such a solution or perhaps something similar? It is imperative for us to still be able to refresh such configurations on the fly, even if being referenced. Thus, these cannot be packaged with the application itself.

Comment: What is your signal to refresh?

Comment: Generally everything is updated by means of pull requests. Then once these are approved and merged, it is up to us to decide when it is best to refresh. Sometimes it is immediate and sometimes we decide to wait a bit so to notify our users.

Comment: I guess I'm confused about what you are asking for. You could put the queries in `@ConfigurationProperties` files or `@RefreshScope` beans.

Comment: @spencergibb We are already making use of `@ConfigurationProperties`. This is our current solution with a Git backend. However, the inline queries are quite cumbersome and we are asking if it is somehow possible to maintain a Git backend but have a reference to a file with the query rather than having the actual query in the configuration. Also, we do not want the query file packaged with the application as we would like to be able to refresh them on the fly.

Comment: So you can use the https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-config/2.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#_serving_plain_text api to get files that aren't. https://github.com/pivotal-cf/spring-cloud-services-starters/blob/master/spring-cloud-services-config-client-autoconfigure/src/main/java/io/pivotal/spring/cloud/config/client/PlainTextConfigClientImpl.java is a good sample of how to use this.

Comment: @spencergibb Interesting solution. Definitely worthy of a PoC. Many thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

That's funny, we set up almost the same as you did... Although it seems to be good, be very careful with that... Using the `@RefreshScope` on every beans will certainly be useful at first, but then, if you think of the users using your application, they might be impacted by the refresh, as your bean won't exist, the time they get re-created. They might experiences some 500 Internal or similar sometimes.

Anyway, try this : https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_server.html#_file_system_backend
That is what we used in my team. It is connecter to your filesystem... But I don't know the behavior of combining the native search and a git repository... Don't even know if possible. You might have one, but maybe not both. Give it a try.

Comment: To be honest, we only have `@RefrshScope` on a couple of beans. Most of the beans we refresh are annotated with `@ConfigurationProperties` which still get refreshed when the endpoint is triggered. You bring up a good point, but we are not exactly client facing so we can afford a few seconds downtime every now and then. 

I'm aware of the filesystem backend. Unfortunately it does not seem that we can make use of both backends. It would be very interesting if someone managed to find a suitable solution for such a use case.